# Can I upgrade my iPad 2 to iOS 9 after the release of iOS 10?

Tags: ios, upgrade

With the imminent release of iOS 10, I'm wondering if I should upgrade my iPad 2 to iOS 9 now. Specifically, I'd like to know if I will still be able to do that after iOS 10 is released? (Currently at iOS 7)

I know that I'll be forced to upgrade one day, as some app I like won't support iOS 7 anymore, but I'm also aware that it will make my iPad even slower, so I'd like to hold off as long as possible. But, I don't want to end up in a situation where I can't upgrade to 9 anymore, e.g. because Apple stops signing for 9 after the release of 10?

Comment: IIRC sometimes Apple has continued to sign firmware that is not the latest so if and when iOS 10 comes out they may still be signing iOS 9. Not a risk I would take however. Or if the iPad 2 is not supported then Apple will still be signing iOS 9 - only for the iPad 2 so you can always upgrade to iOS 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[iOS 10 is not available for the iPad 2](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios-10/).

Because of that, you will continue to be able to upgrade to iOS 9.3.5 **at any time in the future**. Apple continues to sign the last available firmware for all devices, which will be iOS 9.3.5 for the iPad 2.

Examples of how the last supported version of iOS for a device continues to be signed: [here](https://api.ineal.me/tss/status)

Answer (score 0):

You are free to upgrade your device **anytime**, if current iOS has support for your iPad device version.

While you're not sure, google some reviews what's the performance of iOS 9 like on iPad 2, as this process is just one way and you cannot get back older iOS.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer to Legolas's question. Leave iOS 10 aside for a minute: their iPad currently has iOS 7, is it possible for them to upgrade it to iOS 8 and if so how? I think the only option available would be the current version supported by that iPad i.e. 9.3.5.

Comment: @nekomatic Thanks for your reaction. Please write, why do you think he is asking about iOS 8.0? Legolas wrote 'I don't want to end up in a situation where I can't upgrade to 9 anymore'. An my answer is for this. As well as for theirs 'I'd like to know if I will still be able to do that after iOS 10 is released'.

Comment: OK, we're confused because Legolas wrongly assumed that their device will take iOS 10. You're correct that they will continue to be able to update to the latest version supported by their device. However if someone has a device that **is** supported by iOS 10, then after iOS 10 is released they will no longer be able to update it to iOS 9.x - just as if you currently have a device that is supported by iOS 9, you cannot update it to iOS 8.

Comment: @necomatic Yes and that's why i wrote 'as this process is just one way and you cannot get back older iOS.'

Comment: I think the part of your answer I found misleading was *Apple won't stop signing [a] supported version, just because of [the] release of [a] new iOS*. Yes, they will, **if** the newer version supports your device.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for warning and language corrections as well. I rather deleted that sentence.